# bcm_host_init() fails after using execl

Tags: opengles

I have a EGL app. 
After downloading a executable update, I close the app and execute a execl.
The new instance crashes when calling bcm_host_init();

I checked, and the call to bcm_host_deinit(); is being called before the execl is made.

What can I do to restart the app? Why does bcm_host_init() crash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was using vc_display_close(...) before the fork. 
bcm_host_deinit(); does nothing...

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.